# Powershell: Storing data

Tags: powershell, object, data-structures

I would appreciate if someone could help me with fundamental ways to store data in a tabulated manner in PowerShell, specifically how to add values to a previously created table.

I'd also appreciate if someone could show a code example of the best way to do this kind of thing.

Apologies in advance if this is too fundamental for this arena. I would appreciate being pointed in a useful direction.

Basically, I want to store a collection of plaintext user names and passwords. Nothing fancy so I don't need encryption (I know about the **PSCredential** object. It's not required)

**Method 1 - Custom Object**

```
$account = New-Object -TypeName PSObject

Add-Member -InputObject $PRCGuest -MemberType NoteProperty `
    -Name UserName -Value ""

Add-Member -InputObject $PRCGuest -MemberType NoteProperty `
    -Name Password -Value ""
```

I know how to assign initial values to this objects members...

```
$account.UserName = "jimbo"
$account.Password = "1234
```

but what is the correct syntax to add further values and is creating an object like this to store lists of data correct?

**Method 2 - Hash table**

```
$account = @{
             "jimbo" = "1234";
             "jimmy" = "2346"
}
```

I've read that you can create a hashtable and then copy the value pairs into a custom object. How is this done and why do you need this intermediate step?

Finally, are there any good books, ideally language agnostic (as I will be learning C++ soon) that show how to efficiently store tables of data in high level object oriented languages.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: *add values to a previously created table* To which table? Where? What kind of table?

Comment: New-Object psobject -Property @{ "jimbo" = "1234"; "jimmy" = "2346" }

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the hashtable method as I think it is cleaner and easier to read. There are a few methods to achieve this depending on which version of PowerShell you are using.

## Example 1

```
  $props = @{

  Property1 = 'one'

  Property2 = 'two'

  Property3 = 'three'

  }

  $object = new-object psobject -Property $props
  $object | Select-Object Property1, Property2
```

## Example 2 REQUIRES V3

```
  $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{

  Property1 = 'one'

  Property2 = 'two'

  Property3 = 'three'


  }
  $OBJ | Select-Object Property1
```

Here is the Link for Reference
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7804.powershell-creating-custom-objects.aspx

Comment: How do I now reference $obj to add to it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Datasets and Datatables are better if you have a lot of data. They act like an in-memory database and can be saved out to an XML file. Beyond that, you would probably benefit from using something like SQLite.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).